# what does this line of code do? player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;

Tags: c++, visual-c++, data-structures

I can`t understand this line 
why we use question mark "?" in it.
there are 2 player 1 and 2 .

```
player = (player % 2) ? 1 : 2;
```

Comment: The line `(player % 2) ? 1 : 2` basically evaluates if `(player % 2)` is true. If it's true, the `1` is selected, otherwise, if it's false, the `2` is selected. The selected value is then assigned to `player`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a conditional `if`, and is the same as:

```
if(player % 2)
    player = 1; // Odd
else
    player = 2; // Even
```

Another way to do this without an `if` branch:

```
player = 2 - (player & 0x01);
```

The least significant bit is zero for even numbers.

Answer (score 3):

It's the [ternary operator](http://www.cprogramming.com/reference/operators/ternary-operator.html).

This line of code will set `player` to `1` if `player` originally was odd, and to `2` if it was even.

Comment: @juanchopanza: right. What I meant to say is it should be used for its return value, not for side effects.

Answer (score 0):

It's the ternary operator. It takes this form:

```
boolean expression ? a : b;
```

Which translates to:

```
If this expression is true, then a else b
```

It's often used as the right-hand expression in assignment operators. In your case `player` is being assigned 1 or 2 based on whether they are even or odd.

Answer (score 0):

It meaning that if the Condition is true so Player have the Value 1 else it have 2.

```
if(player % 2) {
    player = 1;
} else {
    player = 2;
}
```